# Unable to create Request: Bad URL

Tags: objective-c, ios, google-maps

When i try to look for a location like this: `Florida,USA` it goes OK, but when i try it like this: `Florida USA`, i got that error:

```
Unable to create Request (bad url?)
```

The problem belongs with the spaces on the location taped, is there any way to resolve that?

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=%@&sensor=true",theLocationString];
    //Create a URL object.
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    ASIFormDataRequest *request=[ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the problem is that you need to urlencode your string. A space character isn't a valid url string:

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=%@&sensor=true",theLocationString];
//Create a URL object.
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:
                    NSASCIIStringEncoding]];
ASIFormDataRequest *request=[ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
```

If `NSASCIIStringEncoding` doesn't work you could try: `NSUTF8StringEncoding`

..fredrik